# App Engine monitoring dashboard for multiple apps

Tags: monitoring, google-app-engine

I run a number of webapps on Google App Engine. I'm looking for a monitoring dashboard that shows me basic health metrics (HTTP response codes, latency, etc.) from multiple App Engine apps at the same time, on the same page. Ideally it should also pull metrics from Google's APIs directly, as opposed to requiring me to instrument my code.

So far, everything I've seen only shows a single app at a time: [Google Cloud Console](http://console.developers.google.com/appengine/), Google's [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.cloudconsole), [Stackdriver](http://www.stackdriver.com/), [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/), etc. [HawkEye](https://portal.appscale.com/) looks like it might work, but it hasn't managed to actually pull up any of my apps' metrics yet.

I tried making a simple HTML page with iframes for each of my apps' monitoring dashboards, but Google blocks that with `X-Frame-Options`. :/

Also, these are side projects, so I'm willing to pay a little if necessary, e.g. $10s/mo, but not more.

([Migrated here manually from StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512415/app-engine-monitoring-dashboard-for-multiple-apps))

Answer (score 1):

**HawkEye can be used for monitoring multiple GAE apps.** You add each app ID you want to monitor and it should deploy a sensor next to your GAE app as a separate version.

Once regirested, you get **API call latency in milliseconds and graphs showing the latest trend**.
You can also configure it to send you **email notifications** when latency goes above a specific threshold that's either auto-configured or something reasonable that you set yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! as i mentioned in the post, i tried hawkeye with a few of my apps, but it never worked. it eventually added a version to my app after a few days (!) and started pinging `/health?...`, but no metrics ever showed up in the hawkeye dashboard.

Comment: I am actually part of the AppScale team that wrote HawkEye and I'd be happy to help you get started with app monitoring. I'll send you an email and we can go from there. :)